# Dynamic programming in the functional paradigm

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, dynamic-programming

I'm looking at [Problem thirty one](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=31) on Project Euler, which asks, how many different ways are there of making £2 using any number of coins of 1p, 2p, 5p, 10p, 20p, 50p, £1 (100p) and £2 (200p).

There are recursive solutions, such as this one in Scala (credit to Pavel Fatin)

```
def f(ms: List[Int], n: Int): Int = ms match {
  case h :: t =>
    if (h > n) 0 else if (n == h) 1 else f(ms, n - h) + f(t, n)
  case _ => 0
} 
val r = f(List(1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200), 200)
```

and although it runs fast enough, it's relatively inefficient, calling the `f` function around 5.6 million times.

I saw someone else's solution in Java which was programmed dynamically (credit to wizeman from Portugal)

```
final static int TOTAL = 200;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] coins = {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200};
    int[] ways = new int[TOTAL + 1];
    ways[0] = 1;

    for (int coin : coins) {
        for (int j = coin; j <= TOTAL; j++) {
            ways[j] += ways[j - coin];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Result: " + ways[TOTAL]);
}
```

This is much more efficient and passes the inner loop only 1220 times.

While I could obviously translate this more or less verbatim into Scala using `Array` objects, is there an idiomatic functional way to do this using immutable data structures, preferably with similar conciseness and performance?

I have tried and become stuck trying to recursively update a `List` before deciding I'm probably just approaching it the wrong way.

Comment: I looked at the Scala version for 1 minute and could tell how it worked. Looked at the Java one for 5 minutes, and I still don't know how it works. For me a good example showing that functional is not more complex than imperative.

Comment: @huynhjl But beside looking at a functional and imerative algortihm, you're at the same time looking at a canonical and optimized algorithm.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Whenever some part of a list of data is computed based on a previous element, I think of `Stream` recursion. Unfortunately, such recursion cannot happen inside method definitions or functions, so I had to turn a function into a class to make it work.

```
class IterationForCoin(stream: Stream[Int], coin: Int) {
  val (lower, higher) = stream splitAt coin
  val next: Stream[Int] = lower #::: (higher zip next map { case (a, b) => a + b })
}
val coins = List(1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200)
val result = coins.foldLeft(1 #:: Stream.fill(200)(0)) { (stream, coin) =>
  new IterationForCoin(stream, coin).next
} last
```

The definitions of `lower` and `higher` are not necessary -- I could easily replace them with `stream take coin` and `stream drop coin`, but I think it's a little clearer (and more efficient) this way.

Comment: Is the stream really what is doing the trick here, or is it the fact that higher and lower are being reused (so this is the "storage" trick that prevents duplication of effort?)

Comment: @PeteyPabPro Both. The `Stream` makes it possible to do the recursion on the data, which makes it possible to do the reuse.

Comment: @DanielCSobral But one can create a slightly modified version without the `Stream`, correct? (see my answer below).

Comment: Might also be interesting to see how elegant it can be to use lazy datastructures to do dynamic programming: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Dynamic_programming_example

Answer (score 16):

I don't know enough about Scala to comment specifically on that, but the typical way to translation a DP solution in to a recursive one is to memoization (use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). This is basically caching the result of your function for all values of the domain

I found this as well http://michid.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/function_mem/.  HTH

Comment: While it works and is my favorite solution, I observed huge performance issues with this. Using while loops on arrays was by far the most efficient solution (on Scala 2.8.1), and I am talking (at least) factors in the tens here.

Comment: @Raphael: when the running time is only a few milliseconds, a couple of factors of ten don't really matter!

Comment: @Gareth I should probably have changed the problem so that it asks for the number of ways to make something larger like £10. The dynamic solution completes instantly with 7620 loops. The recursive solution is still running after 10 minutes and I suspect the monetary value required for the computation to take longer than the lifetime of the universe would not be very high.

Comment: @Luigi: Raphael and I are comparing dynamic programming with recursion-plus-memoization, not recursion on its own.

Comment: I would be interested to see how concisely memoization could be implemented, if anyone who knows what they're doing fancies having a go... :)

Comment: @Luigi Here's a pretty concise implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640823/in-scala-2-8-what-type-to-use-to-store-an-in-memory-mutable-data-table/3640889#3640889.  You can make it even more concise by factoring out the logic required to handle multiple arities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875767/scala-memoize-a-function-no-matter-how-many-arguments-the-function-takes/5877235#5877235.

Comment: @Raphael: I wonder if some of the slowdown comes from using lists as map keys.  If you use integers as map keys (one way of looking at what [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638933/dynamic-programming-in-the-functional-paradigm/6643623#6643623) does), does that cause a speedup?

Comment: I used (tuples of) integers as map keys. In my case, we talk 90min vs "abort after 12h", not milliseconds. Profiling the coded showed _lots_ of (un)boxing going on, but most of the time was spent retrieving values from the hashmaps used for storage. I guess they were stored awfully scattered on the heap, not taking advantage of locality of accesses (as loops on arrays do).

Answer (score 11):

Functional dynamic programming can actually be really beautiful in a lazy language, such as Haskell (there's [an article on it](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Dynamic_programming_example) on the Haskell wiki).  This is a dynamic programming solution to the problem:

```haskell
import Data.Array

makeChange :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
makeChange coinsList target = arr ! (0,target)
  where numCoins = length coinsList
        coins    = listArray (0,numCoins-1) coinsList
        bounds   = ((0,0),(numCoins,target))
        arr      = listArray bounds . map (uncurry go) $ range bounds
        go i n   | i == numCoins = 0
                 | otherwise     = let c = coins ! i
                                   in case c `compare` n of
                                        GT -> 0
                                        EQ -> 1
                                        LT -> (arr ! (i, n-c)) + (arr ! (i+1,n))

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $  "Project Euler Problem 31: "
                ++ show (makeChange [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200] 200)
```

Admittedly, this uses O(*cn*) memory, where *c* is the number of coins and *n* is the target (as opposed to the Java version's O(*n*) memory); to get that, you'd have to use some technique of capturing mutable state (probably an `STArray`).  However, they both run in O(*cn*) time.  The idea is to encode the recursive solution *almost* directly recursively, but instead of recursing within *go*, we look up the answer in the array.  And how do we construct the array?  By calling *go* on every index.  Since Haskell is lazy, it only computes things when asked to, so the order-of-evaluation stuff necessary for dynamic programming is all handled transparently.

And thanks to Scala's by-name parameters and `lazy val`s, we can mimic this solution in Scala:

```scala
class Lazy[A](x: => A) {
  lazy val value = x
}

object Lazy {
  def apply[A](x: => A) = new Lazy(x)
  implicit def fromLazy[A](z: Lazy[A]): A = z.value
  implicit def toLazy[A](x: => A): Lazy[A] = Lazy(x)
}

import Lazy._

def makeChange(coins: Array[Int], target: Int): Int = {
  val numCoins = coins.length
  lazy val arr: Array[Array[Lazy[Int]]]
    = Array.tabulate(numCoins+1,target+1) { (i,n) =>
        if (i == numCoins) {
          0
        } else {
          val c = coins(i)
          if (c > n)
            0
          else if (c == n)
            1
          else
            arr(i)(n-c) + arr(i+1)(n)
        }
      }
  arr(0)(target)
}

// makeChange(Array(1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200), 200)
```

The `Lazy` class encodes values which are only evaluated on demand, and then we build an array full of them.  Both of these solutions work for a target value of 10000 practically instantly, although go much larger and you'll run into either integer overflow or (in Scala, at least) a stack overflow.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, here's the memoized version of Pavel Fatin's code. I'm using Scalaz memoization stuff, though it's really simple to write your own memoization class.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

val memo = immutableHashMapMemo[(List[Int], Int), Int]
def f(ms: List[Int], n: Int): Int = ms match {
  case h :: t =>
    if (h > n) 0 else if (n == h) 1 else memo((f _).tupled)(ms, n - h) + memo((f _).tupled)(t, n)
  case _ => 0
} 
val r = f(List(1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200), 200)
```

Comment: @Luigi you use a stack too small. :-) The overflow has nothing to do with the memoization -- since there are two calls to `f`, one of them will never be tail recursive. In this case, consider that the first call will recurse with the same `ms` parameter, decreasing `n` by `h` each time until `n == h` or `h > n`. When first called, `n` will start as 750, and `h` as 1, so it will recurse 750 times. I tried ten pounds without problem, but I usually set `-Xss1m`.

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, here is a slight variant of the answer above that doesn't use `Stream`:

```
object coins {
  val coins = List(1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200)
  val total = 200
  val result = coins.foldLeft(1 :: List.fill(total)(0)) { (list, coin) =>
    new IterationForCoin(list, coin).next(total)
  } last
}

class IterationForCoin(list: List[Int], coin: Int) {
  val (lower, higher) = list splitAt coin
  def next (total: Int): List[Int] = {
    val listPart = if (total>coin) next(total-coin) else lower
    lower ::: (higher zip listPart map { case (a, b) => a + b })
  }
}
```