# Synchronizing on function parameter for multithreaded memoization

Tags: multithreading, scala, asynchronous, memoization, thread-synchronization

My core question is: how can I implement synchronization in a method on the combination of the object instance and the method parameter?

Here are the details of my situation. I'm using the following code to implement memoization, adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19065888/807674):

```
/**
 * Memoizes a unary function
 * @param f the function to memoize
 * @tparam T the argument type
 * @tparam R the result type
 */
class Memoized[-T, +R](f: T => R) extends (T => R) {

  import scala.collection.mutable

  private[this] val cache = mutable.Map.empty[T, R]

  def apply(x: T): R = cache.getOrElse(x, {
    val y = f(x)
    cache += ((x, y))
    y
  })
}
```

In my project, I'm memoizing `Future`s to deduplicate asynchronous API calls. This worked fine when using `for...yield` to map over the resulting futures, created with the standard `ExcecutionContext`, but when I upgraded to [Scala Async](https://github.com/scala/async/) for nicer handling of these futures. However, I realized that the multithreading that library uses allowed multiple threads to enter `apply`, defeating memoization, because the `async` blocks all executed in parallel, entering the "orElse" thunk before `cache` could be updated with a new `Future`.

To work around this, I put the main apply function in a `this.synchronized` block:

```
def apply(x: T): R = this.synchronized {
  cache.getOrElse(x, {
    val y = f(x)
    cache += ((x, y))
    y
  })
}
```

This restored the memoized behavior. The drawback is that this will block calls with different params, at least until the `Future` is created. I'm wondering if there is a way to set up finer grained synchronization on the combination of the `Memoized` instance and the value of the `x` parameter to `apply`. That way, only calls that would be deduplicated will be blocked.

As a side note, I'm not sure this is truly performance critical, because the synchronized block will release once the `Future` is created and returned (I think?). But if there are any concerns with this that I'm not thinking of, I would also like to know.

Comment: Have you considered using an actor? Then client code would never block on responses, and only a single thread will touch `cache`.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but based on what little I know, that sounds like a more idiomatic solution. Could you explain more or provide a link to how this works for consuming an API from within the controller code for a web response?

Comment: Well, per my understanding, multithreading cannot help much for establishing memoization: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20462893/2073130

Answer (score 1):

Akka actors combined with futures provide a powerful way to wrap over mutable state without blocking. Here is a simple example of how to use an Actor for memoization:

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.util.Timeout
import akka.pattern.ask
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class Memoize(system: ActorSystem) {
  class CacheActor(f: Any => Future[Any]) extends Actor {
    private[this] val cache = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[Any, Future[Any]]

    def receive = {
      case x => sender ! cache.getOrElseUpdate(x, f(x))
    }
  }

  def apply[K, V](f: K => Future[V]): K => Future[V] = {
    val fCast = f.asInstanceOf[Any => Future[Any]]
    val actorRef = system.actorOf(Props(new CacheActor(fCast)))
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)
    import system.dispatcher
    x => actorRef.ask(x).asInstanceOf[Future[Future[V]]].flatMap(identity)
  }
}
```

We can use it like:

```
val system = ActorSystem()
val memoize = new Memoize(system)
val f = memoize { x: Int =>
  println("Computing for " + x)
  scala.concurrent.Future.successful {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    x + 1
  }
}
import system.dispatcher
f(5).foreach(println)
f(5).foreach(println)
```

And "Computing for 5" will only print a single time, but "6" will print twice.

There are some scary looking `asInstanceOf` calls, but it is perfectly type-safe.

Comment: Upvoted because I think this is a great tool to have. I'm still considering whether it makes sense to adopt, as it is a lot of additional boilerplate to take on.

Comment: This will also cache failed futures.