# scala: alias for a keyword?

Tags: scala

is there a way to create an alias for a scala keyword? in particular i have some boilerplate syntax that involves "val" and in order to make it easier to read i'd like to be able to type something "@@" instead and have that translated to val.

Edit:

In some cases, it might be very convenient to be able to replace "lazy val", not just "val". The use case has to do with a function that acts as a python decorator. It looks like this:

```
lazy val function = Decorate(function_ _)
def function_(x: Int, ...) = { ... }
```

it would be a lot nicer if it looked like this:

```
@ function = Decorate(function_ _)
def function_(x: Int, ...) = { ... }
```

just so that there's not a val stacked on top of a def, where both names are extremely similar. (the function_ name is not meant to be called, so it's the cleanest to make the names similar.)

Comment: It would be useful to have more details of the use-case. @@ is only one character shorter and not obviously easier to read. It sounds like something a text preprocessor could handle if you really need it.

Comment: @paul agreed, updated with an edit. thanks!

Comment: Related questions: [scala: memoize a function no matter how many arguments the function takes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875767/scala-memoize-a-function-no-matter-how-many-arguments-the-function-takes) and [scala: trait for a Function object with variable length arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798045/scala-trait-for-a-function-object-with-variable-length-arguments)

Comment: I edited out a redundant `val` keyword in your post.  If it was there intentionally, note that the code would not have compiled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there isn't.

(filler so SO will let me post)

Answer (score 1):

Ouch! This isn't particularly idiomatic Scala.

To start with, you're naming a method "`function_`", they're not the same thing, a method is simply a member of some class, a Function is an object in its own right (although a method can be "lifted" to a function by the compiler, in a similar fashion to the autoboxing of primitives).

Second, what is `Decorate`?  The initial uppercase letter suggests that it's a singleton, therefore an object and the only actual "Function" in that expression!

Could you post a bit more info as to what the method and decorator actually do, so that I can give you a better example as to how you might achieve the same in Scala?

Comment: Guessing from the poster's previous line of questions, `Decorate` is something like the `Memoize` object at the bottom of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875767/scala-memoize-a-function-no-matter-how-many-arguments-the-function-takes/5877235#5877235)

Comment: Even `Decorate` is not really a function: its `apply` method has type parameters and an implicit argument.  However, I suspect that the name of the method isn't really critical to the poster's question. It might just as well be `foo_` with an associated `foo` function.

Comment: @aaron - True, though I feel that a failure to appreciate the distinction, and lack of knowledge of methods such as `compose` on functions, coupled with the need to suffix `_` after a method name to force partial application are all contributing factors to the OP's problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one could write a Scala Compiler Plugin to achieve this. At least the Eclipse Plugin actually uses the original Scala Compiler, so it **might** actually work nicely with the IDE.

Other then that: Daniel C. Sobral is correct: No, there isn't.

Still it sounds like a lot of trouble for a little gain.

Answer (score 0):

If `function_` is never meant to be called directly, why not write

```
lazy val function = Decorate { (x: Int, ...) => ... }
```

or even

```
/**
 * This version makes it more explicit that it's a function value.
 */
lazy val function: (Int, ...) => ReturnType =
   Decorate { (x, ...) => ... }
```

Some caution is advised: conciseness and terseness are two different things.  Here, it looks like you're trying to buy a few keystrokes at a very high price in terms of readability.

**Update:**

If you really want to achieve a simpler syntax for this sort of thing, you *will need* a compiler plugin. If you're going to go that far, I'd suggest using an annotations-based syntax that's likely to be pretty intuitive for Java/Scala developers:

```
@decorate(Memoize)
def slowFn(i: Int) = { ... }
```

Comment: you're right that moving Decorate inside "function" eliminates this need. the downside is that people then have to write functions using two different syntaxes - one with val, and the other with the cleaner "def fn(arg: ...)". that might hurt readability a lot.

Comment: I can see your point of view, but this is really an inherent issue with the language itself.  You can only declare *functions* (or other values) with `val`, and you can only declare *methods* with `def`.  Programmers will therefore have to understand both syntaxes to comprehend the language.